# Where could I search between windows desktop gadgets

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

Formerly I could search on Microsoft website (Think [gallery.live.com](http://gallery.live.com)) for a bunch of gadgets and access to thousands of them. But What happened that now there are only some limit number of gadgets accessible on [this address](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets) and Where have gone all other gadgets? (***And since when?***)

Also Now in the "gallery.live.com" you are referred to useless mentioned link above too (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/personalize/gadgets) that there's just a bit number of gadgets without search capability for more.

Comment: I'm afraid they're gone.. Maybe some sites out there would offer unofficial mirrors, but Microsoft nixed Gadgets in favor of the new paradigm in Windows 8

Comment: ^ sounds like an Answer to me.  I was just there a few days ago, and it was all there, same place.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo wow.What a bad gesture. Thanks for the information anyway

Comment: @Psycogeek : Not really, an answer would be if someone could find the mirror gallery out there, somewhere